# Two conditions in if (only positive numbers without letters)

Tags: shell-script

I have to write script which will accept only positive numbers and no letters/ words.

I've created two if conditions but they don't work together. When I delete one the other one works perfectly fine. How can I connect them?

```
    if [[ ${@:2} -lt 0 ]]; then
        shift
        echo "error, only positive"
        exit 3
    fi

    if [[ ${@:2} == [a-zA-Z] ]]; then
        echo "error, no letters allowed"
        exit 4
    fi
```

My script is executed by this line:
`./script.sh file.txt arg1 arg2 arg3 ...`
so any of arg1, arg2 can't be for example -1 or a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably iterate over all the arguments and test each, and if you are fine with a single test for both things you could do something like the following, which will ensure all the arguments have only digits in them (so no `-` or letters, but also no decimal)

```
pattern='[^0-9]'
for arg; do
    if [[ $arg =~ $pattern ]]; then
        printf 'Unacceptable option: %s\n' "$arg"
        exit 3
    fi
done
```

if you want the separate tests to have different error messages and exit codes you could do those within the `for` loop and test `arg` which will get each command line option in turn

Comment: Thanks, but I've got a question. [^0-9] are all characters other then numbers and then there is statement $arg =~ $pattern so doesn't it mean that if argument is pattern (something other then number) printf this message. Why did you write =~ instead of =?

Comment: @codddeer123 `=~` uses a regular expression search, so here we are checking to see if we can match anything that is not a digit anywhere in the string.  If we find any match, we reject the argument.  Since `-` is required for negative numbers and you wanted to reject letters, those would be found by our regex (as would any white space that was in an argument or if there was other punctuation as well)

Answer (score 2):

You can also take advantage of the bash comparison operators like this :

```
if [ $arg -eq $arg -a $arg -ge 0 ] 2>/dev/null ;then  
  echo "accepted"
else 
  echo "not accepted"
fi
```

The trick is that if you compare with -eq two non numeric arguments bash will raise an error (that we sent to /dev/null).